# Error : In updating the Data using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm Creating a cms website, i have got one issue which im trying to fix it but not getting solved, please can anyone guide me in this. The issue im facing is that when i try to update my records everything is getting fetched except one thing that is the multi-select option, if the databse contain only one multi-select option its retriving,but in case if their is two or anything more than one in the database its not getting retrived. please can anyone try to help me in this please.

Error which im getting is

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Array to string conversion
>
> Filename: models/Contact_model.php
>
> Line Number: 230
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\models\Contact_model.php
>   Line: 230 Function: _error_handler
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\controllers\Home.php
>   Line: 444 Function: portfolio_update
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Controller(Home.php)

```
    //Updating the Records 
    public function portfolio_update($id)
    {
        //$id=$this->input->get('id');
        $result['data']=$this->Contact_model->portfolio_byid($id);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('type[]', 'Type');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('update_portfolio',$result);
        } 

        else 
        {
            $config['upload_path']   = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            $title=$this->input->post('title');
            $type= $this->input->post('type');

            if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
            {
                $fi= $this->upload->data('file_name');
                $file = ("uploads/".$result['data'][0]->filename);
                //delete the existing file if needed
                if (file_exists($file)) {
                    unlink($file);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                $fi= $result['data'][0]->filename;
            }
            $this->Contact_model->portfolio_update($title,$type,$fi,$id);
            echo 'Successfully updated your record';
            //exit();
        } 
    }
```

Model(Contact_model.php)

```
    //Updatng the record
    function portfolio_update($title,$type,$fi,$id)
    {
        $query=$this->db->query("update portfolio1 SET first_content='$title',type='$type',filename='$fi' where ID='".$id."'");
    }
```

view(update_portfolio.php)

```
    <body>
     <?php
      $i=1;
      foreach($data as $row)
      {
      ?>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="container">

                    <h5 style="color:#ff1a1a">Select Section</h5>
                    <?php   $array = array('Creative'=>'Creative','Photography'=>'Photography','Development'=>'Development');
                            echo form_multiselect('type[]',$array,$row->type);
                    ?>
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("type");?></span><br><br>

                    <br><input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-success" value="Update Records"/>

                </div>   
        </form>
        <?php } ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: set `$type = implode(',',$type)` before query in your model then run query since your $type variable is an array you have to convert it into string , or just change ur logic to update the data

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Filename: controllers/Home.php

Line Number: 428

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 428
Function: implode

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter_try\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: how im getting such errors sir when their are more than one value in select option then its showing like this

Comment: It's OK sir I fixed the issue I had to use the explode function in order to fetch it from database. I did it error got fixed. Anyway thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your type field is an checkbox array value So you can't just directly insert an array into database

```
$type= $this->input->post('type');
```

this is an array you get when you post it on server side, So you need to convert into comma separated string by implode function of php and then insert into database. Also you can use comma separated values to show selected values by converting them into array by explode function.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, Message: Array to string conversion, in Filename: models / Contact_model.php. But the origin of the actual error from the Controller. Please try to change in the following sections:

```
      if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
            $fi= $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $file = ("uploads/".$result['data'][0]->filename);
            //delete the existing file if needed
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            $fi= $result['data'][0]->filename;
        }
        $this->Contact_model->portfolio_update($title,$type,$fi,$id);
        echo 'Successfully updated your record';
```

Changed to like this:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
{
    // $fi= $this->upload->data('file_name'); <-- Array
    $get_file = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    $fi = $get_file['file_name']; // <-- String
    $file = ("uploads/".$result['data'][0]->filename);
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Hope can help you.